# how to modify the code so that instead of getting an empty slice get the results

Tags: go

please help me out. I don't get the expected result. it returns me an empty slice .this is my code .problem is that I want to filter my results and then get the results for each provider with the highest rate. but it returns me only an empty slice. Note that the rate and provider id are both in my promotion table. provider id is []int and rate is int.

```
 func AvailablePromotion(c *gin.Context) ([]apply_promotion.Response, error) {
        var req apply_promotion.Request
        if e := c.ShouldBind(&req); e != nil {
            return []apply_promotion.Response{}, e
        }
    
        mapRequest, err := apply_promotion.MakeRequest(req)
        if err != nil {
            return []apply_promotion.Response{}, err
        }
    
        res := apply_promotion.GenerateResponse(mapRequest)
        return res, nil
    
    }
    func MakeRequest(req Request) ([]migrations.Promotion, error) {
        mp := make(map[string]interface{})
        mp["condition"] = req.Condition
    
        promotion, err := available_promotion.Filter(mp["condition"].(map[string]interface{}))
        if err != nil {
            return []migrations.Promotion{}, err
        }
    
        return promotion, nil
    }
    
    package available_promotion
    
    import (
        "promotion-service-go/database/migrations"
        "time"
    )
    
    func Filter(conditions map[string]interface{}) ([]migrations.Promotion, error) {
        currentDate := time.Now().Format("2006-01-02")
        var promotions []migrations.Promotion
        migrations.DB.Where("status = true").
            Preload("Details").Preload("Conditions").
            Where("start <= ? AND end >= ?", currentDate, currentDate).
            Find(&promotions)
    
        
        providerRates := make(map[int]int)
    
        
        for _, p := range promotions {
            for _, providerID := range p.ProviderIds {
                if p.Rate > providerRates[providerID] {
                    providerRates[providerID] = p.Rate
                }
            }
        }
    
        var filteredPromotions []migrations.Promotion
    
        
        for _, p := range promotions {
            status := true
            for _, cond := range p.Conditions {
                if conditions[cond.CKey] != cond.CValue {
                    status = false
                    break
                }
            }
            if !status {
                continue
            }
            for _, providerID := range p.ProviderIds {
                if p.Rate == providerRates[providerID] {
                    filteredPromotions = append(filteredPromotions, p)
                    break
                }
            }
        }
    
        return filteredPromotions, nil
    }
```